# How to drop certain elements from a list typed column in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

Suppose I have polars Dataframe with a list column type of strings:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────┐
│ words                             │
│ ---                               │
│ list[str]                         │
╞═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["i", "like", "the", "pizza"]     │
│ ["the", "dog", "is", "runnig"]    │
│ ["me", "and", "my", "friend", "a… │
└───────────────────────────────────┘
```

And I would like to filter stop words from every list.
Is there any builtin function in Polars to achievce my goal?

I can apply some custom function:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "words": [['i', 'like', 'the', 'pizza'],
              ['the', 'dog', 'is', 'runnig'],
              ['me', 'and', 'my', 'friend', 'are', 'playing']]
})
STOP_WORDS = ['the']
filtered_df = df.with_columns(
    pl.col('words').map_elements(lambda words: [word for word in words if word not in STOP_WORDS])
```

However, it stated [here](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.map_elements.html) that custom UDFs are much slower, so I prefer native API based solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```py
df.with_columns(
    words_filtered=pl.col("words").list.eval(
        pl.element().filter(~pl.element().is_in(STOP_WORDS))
    )
)
```

```
In [32]: df.with_columns(
    ...:     words_filtered=pl.col("words").list.eval(
    ...:         pl.element().filter(~pl.element().is_in(STOP_WORDS))
    ...:     )
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[32]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ words                 ┆ words_filtered        │
│ ---                   ┆ ---                   │
│ list[str]             ┆ list[str]             │
╞═══════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ ["i", "like", "the",… ┆ ["i", "like", "pizza… │
│ ["the", "dog", "is",… ┆ ["dog", "is", "runni… │
│ ["me", "and", "my", … ┆ ["me", "and", "my", … │
└───────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 6):

[`.set_difference()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.set_difference.html) could also be an option.

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("words").list.set_difference(STOP_WORDS)
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ words                                           │
│ ---                                             │
│ list[str]                                       │
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ ["i", "like", "pizza"]                          │
│ ["runnig", "dog", "is"]                         │
│ ["me", "and", "my", "friend", "are", "playing"] │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

The "set" approach also removes duplicates which may not be desired.

```py
>>> pl.Series([["a", "a", "a", "b", "c"]]).list.set_difference(["c", "d"])
shape: (1,)
Series: '' [list[str]]
[
    ["a", "b"]
]
```