# Dropping elements from lists in a nested Polars column

Tags: python, python-polars

How do I get this behaviour:

```
(pl.Series(['abc_remove_def', 'remove_abc_def', 'abc_def_remove']).str.split('_')
   .map_elements(lambda x: [y for y in x if y != 'remove']).list.join('_')
)
```

Without using the slower `map_elements`? I have tried using `.list.eval` and `pl.element()` but I can't find anything that actually excludes elements from a list by name (i.e. by the word 'remove' in this case)

Comment: You can use `pl.element().filter()` inside `.list.eval()` but Is performing `.str.split()` the actual use-case here? i.e. are you really starting off with strings and want to remove "delimited" words from the string?

Comment: @jqurious No, it is just an example (I realise that, starting from the first series, I can remove the substrings by other polars methods). But the data I actually have is already in the list format and I am looking to remove a specific word from the lists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77770290/

Comment: You can combine explode, arg_where, and gather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`list.eval`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.list.eval.html), in combination with [`filter`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.filter.html) would work as following:

```
# list_eval
(pl
   .Series(['abc_remove_def', 'remove_abc_def', 'abc_def_remove']).str.split('_')
   .list.eval(pl.element().filter(pl.element() != 'remove'))
)
```

That said, [`list.set_difference`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.list.set_difference.html) as suggested by @jqurious is the most straightforward and fastest:

```
# list_set_difference
(pl
   .Series(['abc_remove_def', 'remove_abc_def', 'abc_def_remove']).str.split('_')
   .list.set_difference(['remove'])
)
```

Output:

```
shape: (3,)
Series: '' [list[str]]
[
    ["abc", "def"]
    ["abc", "def"]
    ["abc", "def"]
]
```

###### Timings and differences

lists of 3 items
[image: polars timing comparison remove item list]

lists of 100 items with many duplicates
[image: polars timing comparison remove item list]

lists of 100 items without duplicates
[image: polars timing comparison remove item list]

*NB. the timings exclude the creation of the Series.*

Additionally, it is important to note that `list.set_difference` would also remove duplicated values.

For instance on:

```
s = pl.Series(['abc_remove_abc_def', 'remove_abc_def']).str.split('_')

# output after set_difference
shape: (2,)
Series: '' [list[str]]
[
    ["abc", "def"]
    ["def", "abc"]
]

# output for the other approaches
shape: (2,)
Series: '' [list[str]]
[
    ["abc", "abc", "def"]
    ["abc", "def"]
]
```

Comment: If the `group_by_agg` and `explode` scenarios in your graph refer to my answer, maybe rename that as `gather` and `filter` since both of my scenarios use both `group_by_agg` and `explode`. One note about the set_difference approach is that it drops duplicates so if you had "abc_remove_abc_def" then it'd drop the extra abc so just be careful with that.

Comment: @Dean good idea, I updated. Could you maybe add comments `# gather`/`#filter` in your code?

Comment: I got curious so I ran benchmarks too. I think the log scale on the y doesn't show how much worse map_elements is. Gather is pretty bad too but it's not as bad as map. Interestingly filter was the best performance for me, with n=1M and items per list of around 50.

Comment: @Dean interesting, can you show how you did it? I had constructed the series with 101 items using `pl.Series([['abc', 'def']*50+['remove'] for _ in range(n)])`. Since the duplicates might change the behavior I now also tested list with all unique items (`pl.Series([list(map(str, range(100)))+['remove'] for _ in range(n)])`) and list_eval/filter/list_different are almost equal for a large enough Series. I updated the graphs :)

Comment: For reference, [here](https://pastebin.com/RrqSWrM5) is the testing code.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/deanm0000/757c2b823746ea76e5ae349126273c40) `n` is the number of rows and `j` is the approximate number of items per row. I say approximate because it's random.

Comment: Thanks @Dean! [graph of all j combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT0EG.png), [graph per j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHoaL.png) ([linear scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ1iF.png) − I find it more difficult to read)

Comment: what graph library is that?

Comment: And I realized I had forgotten to press "Save edit", so my graph is now there ;)

Comment: Matplotlib/seaborn. Feel free to use the images in your answer if you like. Versions with better legend ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfyfc.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyGtL.png))

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways (see mozway's answer for benchmarks)

### gather (don't use this one)

```
(pl.select(a=pl.Series(['abc_remove_def', 'remove_abc_def', 'abc_def_remove']).str.split('_'))
 .with_row_index('i')
 .group_by('i')
 .agg(pl.col('a').list.gather(pl.arg_where(pl.col('a').explode()!="remove")).first())
 .select('a')
)
```

OR

### filter

```
(pl.select(a=pl.Series(['abc_remove_def', 'remove_abc_def', 'abc_def_remove']).str.split('_'))
 .with_row_index('i')
 .explode('a')
 .filter(pl.col('a')!='remove')
 .group_by('i')
 .agg('a')
 .select('a')
)
```

The first way, with this exact data, seems to be a tiny bit faster, with bigger data it is really slow.

Comment: `explode` is in fact more efficient for large Series ;)

Comment: @mozway They both use explode. In the first we're exploding as an expression which is copy free. In the second the explode is on the df so it copies the other columns' data.

Comment: Sorry, that was an ambiguous shortcut from my side, I meant the full column`explode`.